# How to pass Bags (named-tuples) between activities

Tags: python, etl, bonobo-etl

I'm new to Bonobo library and built a simple flow :

- read a simple CSV called input.csv with header : Header1, Header2, Header3, Header4
- append a new column which is the concatenation of the others
- write the result to a CSV file called output.csv

I'm using the built-in CsvReader and CsvWriter from bonobo to make it simple.
First I was stuck with the CsvReader not sending the headers with cells, and a suggested workaround was adding

> @use_raw_input

annotation for the transformation coming right after the CsvReader. But when passing content to the next activity, the bag is once again losing its header and seen as a simple tuple. It does work only if and only if I explicitely name the fields

> def process_rows(Header1, Header2, Header3, Header4)

My code is as per below (put a breakpoint in process_rows to see that you get a tuple without the header) :

```
import bonobo
from bonobo.config import use_raw_input

# region constants
INPUT_PATH = 'input.csv'
OUTPUT_PATH = 'output.csv'
EXPECTED_HEADER = ('Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3', 'Header4')
# endregion constants


#This is stupid because all rows are checked instead of only the first
@use_raw_input #mandatory to get the header
def validate_header(input):
    if input._fields != EXPECTED_HEADER:
        raise("This file has an unexpected header, won't be processed")
    yield input


def process_rows(*input):
    concat = ""
    for elem in input:
        concat += elem
    result = input.__add__((concat,))
    yield result


# region bonobo + main
def get_graph(**options):
    graph = bonobo.Graph()
    graph.add_chain(bonobo.CsvReader(INPUT_PATH, delimiter=','),
                    validate_header,
                    process_rows,
                    bonobo.CsvWriter(OUTPUT_PATH))
    return graph


def get_services(**options):
    return {}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = bonobo.get_argument_parser()
    with bonobo.parse_args(parser) as options:
        bonobo.run(
            get_graph(**options),
            services=get_services(**options)
        )
# endregion bonobo + main
```

Thanks for your time and help !

Answer (score 1):

I did some investigations and found this "FUTURE" document that I think is what you are after:

http://docs.bonobo-project.org/en/master/guide/future/transformations.html

But it is not implemented.

I found this similar question [Why does Bonobo's CsvReader() method yield tuples and not dicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51673963/why-does-bonobos-csvreader-method-yield-tuples-and-not-dicts/53221088#53221088)

Comment: Thank you Jostein for your links. I've been writing a bit more code in Bonobo now, and I'm not experiencing this weird behavior when not using the built-in Csv writer. I wonder what's wrong with it (or misunderstood, but obviously I'm not the only one who cannot get the point), so I'll let my thread open if anyone's willing to test my code and help somehow.